# Нужна ли здесь запятая перед словом "как" (значение "в качестве" + причинность)?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

*... что нас(,) как профсоюз(,) особенно волнует.* Нужно ли обособлять "как профсоюз" в данном случае? Понятное дело, тут "как" в значении "в качестве", но, может, еще есть дополнительное значение причинности (мол, нас это интересует, так как мы профсоюз).

Comment: Если нечто волнует весь профсоюз, то неуместно это "нас" . Скажите просто: "Профсоюз особенно волнует (ущемление прав трудящихся)".

Comment: Это цитата. Я не прошу изменить фразу, я спрашиваю о пунктуации в конкретном примере.

Comment: Подчиняюсь с грустью. Расставлять знаки препинания в плохо составленных фразах — это как драить палубу корабля с дырявым дном.

Comment: Понимаю. Но я обращаюсь на этот ресурс с цитатами, которые не могу вольно менять. Это устный комментарий, который попал в текст журналиста: важно сохранить точность. За ответы спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

**... что нас, как членов профсоюза, особенно волнует.**

Запятые поставьте, так как обособленный оборот имеет обстоятельственное значение, ср.: ***...что нас особенно волнует, так как мы являемся членами профсоюза.***

Answer (score 3):

**...что нас, как членов профсоюза, особенно волнует.**

Это обособленное приложение с союзом КАК, отнесенное к местоимению, значение причины.

**Значения "в качестве" у этого сочетания вообще нет,** так как нельзя сказать: волнует в качестве членов профсоюза.

**Для сравнения (когда можно сделать выбор):**

Нас послали на конференцию **как членов профсоюза** (в качестве членов профсоюза).

Нас, **как членов профсоюза**, обязали присутствовать на конференции (значение причины, так как мы члены профсоюза).

Answer (score 0):

> ... что нас(,) как профсоюз(,) особенно волнует.
>   Это цитата. Я не прошу изменить фразу, я спрашиваю о пунктуации в конкретном примере

**...что нас, как профсоюз, особенно волнует.**

> Понятное дело, тут "как" в значении "в качестве".

Дело не такое уж понятное. Тут "как" **не** имеет значения "в качестве". Слова "как профсоюз" — это приложение. Приложение может быть выражено существительным с союзом как (Мне, как человеку любопытному, совсем не хочется уходить из комнаты) ([2.4.1. Приложение как разновидность определения)](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/717-241_prilozhenie_kak_raznovidnost_opredeleniya.html)